# dotnet opentelemetry client is not working for httpprotobuf

Tags: asp.net, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm not able to send data with httpprotobuf protocol but everything is working fine with grpc protocol

```
otel.WithTracing(tracing =>
{
    tracing.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
    tracing.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
    tracing.AddSource("CustomActivityName");
    tracing.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
    {
        otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://otel-url:4318/");
        otlpOptions.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
    });
    tracing.AddConsoleExporter();
});
```

I'm bit confused as I'm not seeing any error logs

Answer (score 0):

According to [Exporter Readme](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol/README.md#otlpexporteroptions):

> When using OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf, the full URL MUST be provided, including the signal-specific path v1/{signal}. For example, for traces, the full URL will look like http://your-custom-endpoint/v1/traces.

In your case this would be:

```
otel.WithTracing(tracing =>
{
    tracing.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
    tracing.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
    tracing.AddSource("CustomActivityName");
    tracing.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
    {
        otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://otel-url:4318/v1/traces");
        otlpOptions.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.HttpProtobuf;
    });
    tracing.AddConsoleExporter();
});
```